# question about the empire map

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Given a planar map, an empire is a collection of disjoint regions. An empire with $m$ regions is called an $m$-pire. A planar map partitioned into empires is called an empire map.

Is it possible to construct an empire map in the plane with 11 mutually adjacent empires such that 9 of them are 2-pires and 2 are 1-pires?

Comment: You can't get $11$ regions in the plane all mutually adjacent. The best you can do is $4$. Also, what does 2-pires and 1-pires mean?

Comment: @Arthur A certain collection of m disjoint countries is called an empire and am empire consists of m countries is called m-pire.

Comment: @Arthur By the way, why can't 11 regions all mutaully adjacent? Is there any theorem I can use to prove it? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's called the [four colour theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). If more than four regions are all mutually adjacent, you would need more than four colours to colour them. I was unaware of this empire terminology.

Comment: @Arthur The use of "empires" is more than just terminology: an empire is made up of multiple connected regions, so it's possible to have any number of empires mutually adjacent, unlike the case of a planar graph. (But not if, as in this question, there is a restriction on the number of regions in each empire.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Indeed, assume that such a map exists. Let $G$ be its adjacency graph. Then $G$ should have at least ${11 \choose 2}=55$ edges to realize all adjacencies between different empires. On the other hand, $G$ is a planar graph on  $9\cdot 2+2=20$ vertices and by a corollary from Euler’s formula $G$ can have at most $3\cdot 20-6=54<55$ edges.